# How to check element existence using its alias attributes with Mootools

Tags: mootools

How to check element existence using its alias attributes with Mootools

Tried as follows. But its not working,

```
<select alias="school_type" id="15_4_19" name="15_4_19">
    <option label="" value="">Select</option>
    <option selected="selected" label="High School" value="8">High School</option>
    <option label="University" value="9">University</option>
    <option label="Elementary Schools" value="10">Elementary Schools</option>
</select>


if($$('select[alias=school_type]'))
{
    var elv = $$('select[alias=school_type]');
    var schoolType = elv[0].id;

    data['type_id'] = $(schoolType).get('value');
}
```

Any help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$$` was sort of an alias for `document.getElements` (or `Slick.find` now) and will always return a HTML collection--even when with 0 members. hence, the `if ($$())` assertion will not be falsy.

either do `if ($$('selector').length)` or `if (document.getElement('select[alias=foo]'))` instead, which will be `null` or `element object` so will evaluate `falsy`

Rewrite this to:

```
var selectEl = document.getElement('select[alias=school_type]');
if (selectEl) {
    data['type_id'] = selectEl.get('value');
}
```